# Admin Sdk custom claims return null

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm use firebase cloud functions with android create a user with custom claims, i have used custom claims as docs but custom claims = null : (

thanks in advance

[image: Firebase ID Token]

Code :.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

exports.createSellerAccount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const userEmail = data.email;
    const userPassword = data.password;

    return admin.auth().createUser({
        email: userEmail,
        password: userPassword
    }).then((userRecord) => {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        const additionalClaims = {
            premiumAccount: true
        };

        admin.auth().createCustomToken(userRecord.uid, additionalClaims)
            .then(function (customToken) {
                // Send token back to client
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
            });

        return {
            sellerAccount: userRecord
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        // console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
        if (error.code === "auth/email-already-exists") {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('already-exists', error.message);
        } else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', error.message);
        } else {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message);
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're code creates a custom token, instead of adding claims to the existing token. To do the latter, see [Set and validate custom user claims via the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) which contains this example:

> ```
> // Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.
>
> admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
>   // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
>   // next time a new one is issued.
> });
> ```

So just get the UID of the new user and call `setCustomUserClaims` with it. Then wait for it to propagate to the client, or log the token in the node script to ensure that the claims are in there.

Note that I highly recommend you try to isolate your problem going forward. Instead of showing the token in the Android code, log it in your Cloud Functions code. Better yet, rule out Cloud Functions altogether, and just run a local Node.js script.